# Wrap html tags around all text after the first word

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

How can I rewrite this code such that it wraps html tags around the last words after the first word;

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\>)\b\w*\b|^\w*\b/', '<span class="color_red">$0</span>', $atts['title']);
```

At the moment this regular expression will wrap tags around the first word in a string. I have tried this but it does not work;

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\>)\b\w*\b|^\w*\b/', '<span class="color_red">$1</span>', $atts['title']);
```

Here are some examples;

```
Efficiency <span class="color_red">solutions</span>
Renewable <span class="color_red">Energy Solutions</span>
Accidentally <span class="color_red">left the caps lock on and typed something</span>
```

Or please provide another solution that works.

Comment: You can use strip_tags().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I am not trying to strip tags. I want to add tags.

Comment: suppose your string is " Write your description here "
and o/p you want is "write <span>your description here</span>"

Is this correct ?

Comment: Or there is only two words in your string ?

give me your string for the reference

Comment: @Priyank Yes. Everything after the first word should be wraped with tags. I've added some examples.

Comment: $data = "Write your description here";
list($first,$last) = explode(" ", $data,2);
echo $newstring = $first." <span>".$last."</span>";

check this and let me know if it's not worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match everything after the first word until the last non white space

```
preg_replace('/\b[\w\'-]+\W+\K.*\S/s', '<span class="color_red">$0</span>', $atts['title']);
```

- `\b` matches inital [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) of first word
- `[\w'-]+` one or more [word characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), single quote and hyphen in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `\W+` one or more non-word characters
- [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match
- `.*\S` anything until the last non white space character
- `s`-[flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for making the dot match newlines
- if input is utf-8, add `u` flag for [unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) to adjust `\b`, `\w`, `\W`

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CQ0QKC/1)

Comment: how to add on first word?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it with this way also..**

```
$data = "Write your description here";
list($first,$last) = explode(" ", $data,2);
echo $newstring = $first." <span>".$last."</span>";
```